# What are the most tangible benefits to getting your GISP or ESRI Certs?

Tags: certification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GISP - Value of being certified?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2777/gisp-value-of-being-certified)

Looks like I'm only a few presentations or other "contributions to the Profession" points away from being able to apply for my GISP. Has anybody found any actual benefits to getting the certification?

Seems like it might be somewhat arbitrary. Of course it lets people know you have a high level understanding of GIS but beyond that are there any benefits? Salary bumps? Other?

**ADDED**

Additionally, what, if any are the benefits to getting the new [ESRI Certifications](http://training.esri.com/certification/)? ESRI is obviously the most well known GIS software, but there are others... so if one is looking to move forward in their GIS career, what is the best way to do it as far as certs/continuing education go?

Comment: The ESRI certification question is asked at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4883/questions-on-esri-technical-certification.